# Hibernate one-to-one mapping with joined entity

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

There is a problem with one-to-one fetching. I have a simple hierarchy of objects

```
package com.example.demojpa;

public class ClaimCreateRequestFake {
    private Long claimCreateRequestId;
    private ChargebackClaimFake ChargebackClaimFake;    
    ... setters and getters are present for each entity
}

public class AbstractClaimFake {
     private Long claimInstanceId;
     private String abstractDescription;
}

public class ChargebackClaimFake extends AbstractClaimFake {
     private Long claimCreateRequestId;
     private String chargebackDescription;
}
```

Hibernate 5.0.12.Final is used as a JPA provider. I use an orm.xml mapping with JPA 2.0

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<entity-mappings xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm_2_0.xsd"
             version="2.0">

<sequence-generator name="claim_create_request_id_seq"
                    sequence-name="claims.claim_create_request_id_seq"
                    allocation-size="1"
                    initial-value="1"
                    schema="claims"/>

<sequence-generator name="claim_instance_id_seq"
                    sequence-name="claims.claim_instance_id_seq"
                    allocation-size="1"
                    initial-value="1"
                    schema="claims"/>

<entity class="com.example.demojpa.ClaimCreateRequestFake">
    <table name="claim_create_request_fake" schema="claims"/>
    <attributes>
        <id name="claimCreateRequestId">
            <column name="claim_create_request_id"/>
            <generated-value generator="claim_create_request_id_seq" strategy="SEQUENCE"/>
        </id>
        <one-to-one name="chargebackClaimFake" fetch="EAGER">
            <join-column name="claim_create_request_id" referenced-column-name="claim_create_request_id"/>
            <cascade>
                <cascade-all/>
            </cascade>
        </one-to-one>
    </attributes>
</entity>

<entity class="com.example.demojpa.ChargebackClaimFake">
    <table name="chargeback_claim_fake" schema="claims"/>
    <attributes>
        <basic name="claimCreateRequestId">
            <column name="claim_create_request_id"/>
        </basic>
        <basic name="chargebackDescription">
            <column name="chargeback_description"/>
        </basic>
    </attributes>
</entity>

<entity class="com.example.demojpa.AbstractClaimFake">
    <table name="abstract_claim_fake" schema="claims"/>
    <inheritance strategy="JOINED"/>
    <discriminator-column name="dtype"/>
    <attributes>
        <id name="claimInstanceId">
            <column name="claim_instance_id"/>
            <generated-value strategy="SEQUENCE" generator="claim_instance_id_seq"/>
        </id>
        <basic name="abstractDescription">
            <column name="abstract_description"/>
        </basic>
    </attributes>
</entity>
</entity-mappings>
```

When I'm trying to persist ClaimCreateRequestFake object everything works well - there is a valid entry in database for each of described tables. But the problem is occured when I'm trying to use Spring Jpa Repository method findOne(Long id). Extracted ClaimCreateRequestFake object has a null as ChargebackClaimFake reference. I tried to trace the SQL query responsible for ClaimCreateRequestFake extract. The query is:

```
select claimcreat0_.claim_create_request_id as claim_cr1_2_0_, 
chargeback1_.claim_instance_id as claim_in2_0_1_, 
chargeback1_1_.abstract_description as abstract3_0_1_, 
chargeback1_.chargeback_description as chargeba1_1_1_, 
chargeback1_.claim_create_request_id as claim_cr2_1_1_ 
from claims.claim_create_request_fake claimcreat0_ left outer join 
claims.chargeback_claim_fake chargeback1_ on 
claimcreat0_.claim_create_request_id=chargeback1_.claim_instance_id 
left outer join claims.abstract_claim_fake chargeback1_1_ on 
chargeback1_.claim_instance_id=chargeback1_1_.claim_instance_id 
where claimcreat0_.claim_create_request_id=?
```

**claimcreat0_.claim_create_request_id=chargeback1_.claim_instance_id** is used to join a ChargebackClaimFake object, but JPA states

**join-column name="claim_create_request_id" referenced-column-name="claim_create_request_id"**

What am I doing wrong with JPA mapping? Why Hibernate uses such join?

Comment: Looks like an @Inheritance issue.

Comment: Whats the point of using XML? You're using JPA 2.0, so annotations will make your code more readable and easier to maintain.

Comment: Java POJOs are generated from xsd-entries, POJOs rebuild after mvn  clean-package. It is too difficult to set all annotations via special cxf-codegen-plugin.